# Снова вопрос по Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

Имеется такой вот цикл:

```
$req = DB::run("SELECT `games`.*, " . Games::count() . " FROM `games` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT " . $this->page . ", " . $this->message);
while ($row = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $arrayrow[] = $row;
    $arrayrowgenre[] = DB::run("SELECT * FROM `genre` WHERE `id` IN (" . $row['genre'] . ") ORDER BY `id` ASC")->fetchAll();
}
```

Необходимо в шаблон smarty передать значения от `$arrayrowgenre`

Такой вариант не подходит:

```
{foreach $arrayrow as $row key=k}
    {foreach $arrayrowgenre as $genre}
       {$genre.$k.name|esc}<br/>
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

он выводит совсем не те значения.

Comment: А что выводит ?

Comment: Выводит это http://joxi.ru/1A5W53aSnzWepm
А нужно: 
1. Гонки
2. Гонки, инди, аркада
3. Гонки, инди, казуальная игра, аркада

Comment: приведите пример, что у вас находится в массивах `$arrayrow`, `$arrayrowgenre`. (`print_r`). Виноват тут наверное не смарти, а то что вы выбираете и как формируете массивы.

Comment: $arrayrow - http://joxi.ru/ZrJpQa0S9bgEL2

$arrayrowgenre - http://joxi.ru/YmENKW0F0BWpd2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в вашем коде (если не брать расчет какой-то ад при выборке данных из БД) состоит в том, что вместо построения и передачи одной связной модели данных вы передаете туда несколько массивов с какими то индексами.
Соберите данные изначально в нормальный вид, в том числе, используя нормальные имена переменных, тогда с ними и работать будет проще.

```
$model = [];
while ($game = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     $genres = DB::run("SELECT * 
                        FROM `genre` 
                        WHERE `id` IN (" . $game['genre'] . ") 
                        ORDER BY `id` ASC")
                 ->fetchAll();
    $game['genres'] = $genres;
    $model[] = $game;         
}
// $smarty->assign('model', $model); // или иначе передать данные в шаблон
```

в шаблоне вывод таблицы с играми и жанрами будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
{foreach $model as $idx => $game}
<tr class="game" id="{$game.id}">
    <td>{$game.name}</td>
    <td>
       <ul>
       {foreach $game.genres as $genre}
          <li>{$genre.name}</li>
       {/foreach}
       </ul> 
    </td>
</tr>
{/foreach}
```

зы: и почитайте где-нибудь про работу с БД в части выборки данных, а также про сами БД в части их реализации. Не ясно зачем вы фактически храните связи многие-ко-многим сериализованные в поле таблицы.